# debugging cakephp with netbeans - no variables

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans, xdebug

I set up cakephp debugging with netbeans and xdebug following these instructions http://www.tiplite.com/cakephp-debug-in-netbeans/ . I got it working, but I cannot see any variables when I get to the breakpoints

Comment: not related to programming, suitable for Super User http://superuser.com/

Comment: ok. thanks. i will try posting there

Comment: I think this question is fine here in view of the fact that there are more likely to be CakePHP programmers using Netbeans here than on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to enable variable listing in php.ini during debugging.
There is likewise an option for that in NetBeans settings, under PHP.

It is unstable, though.