# debuging cakephp with netbeans - no variables

Tags: php, netbeans, debugging, xdebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [debugging cakephp with netbeans - no variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063410/debugging-cakephp-with-netbeans-no-variables)

i set up cakephp debugging with netbeans and xdebug following these instructions http://www.tiplite.com/cakephp-debug-in-netbeans/ , i got it working, but i cannot see any variables when i get to the breakpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a known bug of xdebug. This means that you will expiriance the same problem in any IDE, not only in NetBeans. You will have to compile the new version if you want it to work - this solution helped me with the same problem.

To get the new xdebug, fallow the instructions here: http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php

Comment: i installed the new version, but now netbeans will not connect to xdebug. i checked. the port is correct... do you have any idea what is going on?

Comment: @vasion do you have all the required settings in php.ini?

Comment: it was not loading because i was using the wrong phpize. i got it to work, but i am struggling to see $this. i can see the variables declared in the function, but not the ones in the class :(